# Folder name in batch file

Tags: batch-file

How can get the name of the folder in a for loop. I have the following directory structure

```
c:\Main\**FolderName1**\FolderName3\somefile.txt
c:\Main\**FolderName2**\FolderName4\somefile1.txt
```

And i want to get the name of the **FolderName1** and **FolderName2** inside a for loop.

This is how i am doing right now:

```
set "errfolderpath=C:\Main\"
FOR /D /R %errfolderpath% %%K in (.\*) DO (
  SET folderName=%%~nK
  echo foldername=!folderName!
)
```

when i run the above program it is printing the name of all the subfolders whereas i just want the name of **FolderName1** and **FolderName2** and not to loop rest of the folders.

I hope i was able to make it clear.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to include some more detail - what exactly is it that you are looping through?

Comment: I have updated the question details. Hope this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/R folder` parameter specifies both the starting folder and the recursive search, while you only need the former and not the latter.

So, just use your root folder with the file mask, like this:

```
set "errfolderpath=C:\Main\"
FOR /D %%K in ("%errfolderpath%*") DO (
  SET folderName=%%~nK
  echo foldername=!folderName!
)
```

Comment: This works great. Except my directory has a . in it for example Waynes.World and it only picks up the word Waynes. Any Suggestions?

Comment: @theB3RV: The `~n` would need to be changed to `~nx`. Using this script as an example, the second SET command would need to look like this: `SET folderName=%%~nxK`. You can read more about these `~`-modifiers in `FOR /?`.

Comment: @AndriyM actually, i just removed the n and left it as `%%~K` and it worked